# What content am I being blocked from editing and why?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, editing, blacklist

Tonight I went to edit [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/184171/how-to-extend-partition) to fix the link, which the poster had entered in BBcode rather than Markdown. When I went to submit the edit, I got this error message, which I've never seen before:

[image: Sorry, posts can't contain that content]

The error says that posts can't contain that content, nor that title. However, the only thing I modified was the link text, so why was I getting that error when the post obviously contained the rest of that content when it was originally posted?

Comment: Ah, just posted [the same question](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1370/unable-to-edit-a-question-because-of-that-content) while you were posting this. Maybe a general error or something wrong with this particular post?

Comment: Hm, strange. Maybe it had something to do with two users trying to edit the same post simultaneously? You'd think there would be a built-in means for handling that though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This particular post happens to be spam, and has been reported to the SO mods.

I have removed it from SU in the meantime. The content blocker most likely picked up on the spam which prevented the editing from happening.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Any idea why the post got through the spam filter when it was created, but was caught when we edited it?

Comment: @nhinkle It was migrated from SO. No checking was done on the SU side.

Comment: Ah, interesting. I would've thought they would have the same spam filters, but evidently not. Thanks for the info!