# Unable to edit a question because of "that content"?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, editing, blacklist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What content am I being blocked from editing and why?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1369/what-content-am-i-being-blocked-from-editing-and-why)

Was trying to edit the following question to fix the broken URL:
https://superuser.com/questions/184171/how-to-extend-partition

Upon submitting I get the following error:

> Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because:
>    * Sorry, posts can't contain that content.
>    * Sorry, post titles can't contain that content.

I literally just fixed the URL and added tick marks around "C:", and the error message doesn't make it clear **what** "that" content is.

What happened? / What did I do wrong? / Something broken?